# Self-hosted docker-registry does not request authentication at root domain, i.e. registry.mydomain.com

Tags: basic-authentication, docker-registry

Along with some node.js apps, I have a self-hosted docker registry served by ubuntu, [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy), and [acme-companion](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion). Basic auth for the registry is setup using `htpasswd`. If I try to navigate to the root domain, such as https://myregistry.com, authentication is not required. If attempting to open https://myregistry.com/v2 or https://myregistry.com/v2/_catalog authentication is requested. Is this expected? If not, how can I pinpoint the reason this happens?

Since authentication succeeds (and fails) when it should on the `/v2` and `/v2/_catalog` paths, I assume the credentials and htpasswd file + location are valid.

```yaml
# compose-registry.yml

version: '3.8'
services:
  registry.mydomain.com:
    image: registry:2.8
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: registry.mydomain.com
    restart: always
    expose:
    - 5000
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - acme-companion
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: registry.mydomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: registry.mydomain.com
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /data
      REGISTRY_AUTH: 'htpasswd'
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: 'basic-realm'
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: '/auth/registry.mydomain.com'
    volumes:
      - data:/data
      - /home/lala/docker-registry/auth:/auth
    networks:
      - registry
volumes:
  data:
networks:
  registry:
```

Comment: Is there some content on the root domain that you need to protect, or some problem this is causing with a tool? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Good question. I would first like to know if this is a gap in my own config or a known docker quirk. I have examined the '/' path and there's nothing there. A 200 response and an empty html page. Mainly I'm just trying to learn about it.

Comment: It's not a documented OCI endpoint, so implementations are free to do anything they want with it: https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md

Comment: That's what I wanted to know! If you care to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OCI distribution-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md) does not specify any behavior for the `/` endpoint, only `/v2/` and below. So OCI registries are free to handle that endpoint any way they wish.

The behavior of the distribution project is going to be related to how they have defined their router/mux in Go, but I didn't spend enough time digging through their code to find the specific location of the behavior difference. If you want your application to be portable to other registries, I'd avoid using an undefined endpoint and stick to `/v2/`.